Correlation Between Laplacian And Convexity Around Point In R^D Euclidean Space
So, in 1D Euclidean space, the Laplacian of a function is simply the second derivative of that function. In this case, the sign of the Laplacian at extremum points will tell us the convexity of that point.
My question is; Does this generalize to n-dimensional Euclidean space?
